# I want to arrange my records date wise from earlier to current within the category

Tags: php, mysql

Query which i used in my code-

```
SET @a:=-1;

SET @b:=0;

SELECT m.allocationid,
       mt.catid,
       mt.catsname,
       r.officername,
       r.desgname,
       r.grade,
       r.cellno,
       IF(mt.catsname = 'E', @a := @a + 2,
       IF(mt.catsname = 'D', 0, @b := @b + 2)) AS
       rwid
FROM   msttransaction m,
       msttemp mt,
       regusers r
WHERE  ( m.ispending = 'Y'
         AND m.statusr = 'Approve'
         AND m.iscancelled = 'No'
         AND m.allocationid IN (SELECT mt.allocationid
                                FROM   msttemp
                                WHERE  mt.quarterid = '082505012')
         AND Substring(m.allocationid, 1, 11) = r.pfnpsno )
        OR ( m.ispending = 'N'
             AND m.type = 'Transit'
             AND m.statusr = 'Approve'
             AND m.iscancelled = 'No'
             AND m.allocationid IN (SELECT mt.allocationid
                                    FROM   msttemp
                                    WHERE  mt.quarterid = '082505012')
             AND Substring(m.allocationid, 1, 11) = r.pfnpsno )
ORDER  BY rwid,
          Substring(m.allocationid, 14)
```

this query shows output as

```
SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId,-14) CatID  CatSName OfficerName        rwid
20160812000000                  4     D       TARUN DANDOTIYA     0
20160911114106                  4     D       Rahul N Chauhan     0
20180601000000                  5     E       ARUN  KUMAR         7
20170403000000                  6     F       VEERSINGH MEENA     2
20160503000000                  5     E       HEMANT  JINDAL      1
20170529000000                  6     F       AJAY RAJ            6
20161227000000                  5     E       G M SRINIVASAN      3
20170526000000                  6     F       S M KELKAR          4
20180621000000                  5     E       JANYU  JINESH       9
20170704000000                  6     F       AJAY SINGH          8
20180504000000                  5     E       GANESH  LONARE      5
20170914000000                  6     F       UMANG DUBEY         10
```

But i want my result as

```
SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId,-14) CatID  CatSName OfficerName        rwid
20160911114106                  4     D       Rahul N Chauhan     0
20160812000000                  4     D       TARUN DANDOTIYA     0
20160503000000                  5     E       HEMANT  JINDAL      1
20170403000000                  6     F       VEERSINGH MEENA     2
20161227000000                  5     E       G M SRINIVASAN      3
20170526000000                  6     F       S M KELKAR          4
20180504000000                  5     E       GANESH  LONARE      5
20170529000000                  6     F       AJAY RAJ            6
20180601000000                  5     E       ARUN  KUMAR         7
20170704000000                  6     F       AJAY SINGH          8
20180621000000                  5     E       JANYU  JINESH       9
20170914000000                  6     F       UMANG DUBEY         10
```

Note-Here i am not showing AllocationId in table output

I want to arrange my output according to date wise i.e. SUBSTRING(m.AllocationId, -14) in my case within the category that means for D category which comes first comes first within the category hope you guys understand,thanks in advance

Comment: Please _remove_ the images, and instead include actual text, formatted as code, so that others may read your question.

Comment: is image is not visible to you clearly?if yes then i will change it into text format

Comment: @VAIBHAVRAWAT Images are hard to read and code is not reproducible, for others to test and fix. It is preferable if you can prepare a DB Fiddle / SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Images are entirely unhelpful. Post proper DDLs

Comment: I updated the format and removed images as you said please help me,thanks in advance @Strawberry,@Tim Biegeleisen,@Madhur Bhaiya

Answer (score 0):

You could order by the category and then by the date:

```
ORDER  BY CatID, Substring(m.allocationid, 14)
```

Comment: It will change my output,i want E and F category alternate after D on higher priority and within D,E,F it will short according to date wise